# How to use byte[] ssl certificate instead of .pem files used in openssl

Tags: openssl, certificate, buffer

My device doesn't have any file system, so I want to convert ssl certificates in .pem format to byte[] and use it in openssl in place of .pem certificated.
Using this openssl x509 -in mycert.pem  -C, I have got the .c file with ... 
unsigned char XXX_certificate[576]={
0x30,0x82,0x02,0x3C,0x30,0x82,0x01,0xA5,0x02,0x10,0x70,0xBA,0xE4,0x1D,0x10,0xD9,
....

How to use this byte [] in openssl. Basically i need to bypass reading of .pem files and ask it to take my XXX_certificate[576] buffer.

Any idea in which file of openssl i should do the changes so that It take this byte array.

Please let me know the changes to be done as well..

Thanks for your support ...

Answer (score 0):

Use [BIO](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bio.html). Create [BIO_new_mem_buf()](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_mem.html) using your data and then read it with [PEM_read_bio_X509()](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/pem.html).